# Windows Service or Asp.net web api RESTful service?

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-web-api, windows-services

I'm developing a C# solution with .NET Framework 4.5.1.

I need to have a program (an object instance) running all the time waiting to receive commands. This program will have a state and depending on this state it will allow some commands or others.

For example, it will have an open and close command. If the state is not openned and the program receives the close command, it won't do anything.

I've thought to create a windows service or a ASP.NET MVC WebApi 2.2 app.

If I choose windows service, the program will be running always but I don't know how to communicate with it (maybe adding it a TCP/IP server).

If I use ASP.NET MVC WebApi 2.2 I can send the commands using POST or PUT messages, but I don't know if I can have an object instance running while the web service is up.

The program is a class that I have to instanced it. This instance will keep its state and a communication with a WCF service.

What do you recommend me?

Comment: You can have a windows service host webapi and its just like any other http endpoint. You may need to run a couple of commands at the command propmpt to give it the right permissions. Just google "hosting web api in windows service" for plenty of examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options from which to choose are strange a little.

You can self-host Web API in windows service, and communicate with service using HTTP. Note, that Web API is about stateless, so, if you need to preserve the state, this should be a persistable data.

As to a way for communicate with windows service, using something other, than Web API - there are number of ways to do this. WCF with TCP/Named Pipes, pure Named Pipes (without WCF), sockets, memory mapped files. You just need to select most appropriate for your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't understand this: "Options from which to choose are strange a little." What do you mean?

Comment: I mean, that the question as it stated (Web API vs Windows service) is incorrect. Web API is a framework to build a RESTful services. Windows service is just an application type, which can host either Web API service(s), or provide some other functionality. They cannot be compared directly.

Comment: Another question: How can I achieve this communication between windows service and Api controllers? I have asked this question about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32374489/pass-servicebase-class-instance-to-apicontroller-hosted-on-it