# Pass ServiceBase class instance to ApiController hosted on it

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, windows-services

I'm developing a Windows Service with a RESTFul web service hosted on it. I'm going to communicate with the windows service throught the windows service.

This is my project structure:
[image]

These are my classes implementation.

```
namespace WindowsService_HostAPI
{
    public partial class SelfHostService : ServiceBase
    {
        private int _value;
        private HttpSelfHostServer _server;
        private static readonly ILog _log = 
            LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        public int Value
        {
            get { return _value; }
            set { _value = value; }
        }

        public SelfHostService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:8080");

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "API",
                routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
               );

            _server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);
            _server.OpenAsync().Wait();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            if (_server != null)
                _server.CloseAsync().Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

And **ValuesController**:

```
namespace WindowsService_HostAPI.Controllers
{
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/Value/")]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetValue()
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;



            return response;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/Value/{value}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage SetValue(int value)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;



            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

**This is only an example**, but I need to communicate the ApiController with the Windows Service class.

I have to modify `SelfHostService.Value` property when someone do a Post (method `SetValue`) setting `value` passed. How can I do that?

Comment: In what way do you want to "comunicate" It is a single app. You can't alter `_value` it is private, you can alter `Value` if you have an instance of `SelfHostService`. But quite what you would expect that to do is unclear. I suspect you are thinking about this the wrong way, unless the windows service has some other defined purpose, then perhaps it's only function should be to host the rest service.

Comment: Yes, I said that this is only an example, and I know that _value is private. I need to create a class instance and keep it alive until Windows Service stops. If I can modify _value value, I could what I need to do. And remember, this is ony an example.

Comment: Cant you use a static property on your SelfHostService for this case. then you do not need the instance. Otherwise you will need dependency injection to solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

> I need to create a class instance and keep it alive until Windows
>   Service stops

The right way to do what you want with Web API is to use [`IDependencyResolver`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.dependencies.idependencyresolver%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). [Here's](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection) the sample (it uses Unity, but you can use any container).

The main concept is that you build up a contract for dependency, e.g.:

```
public interface IValueProvider
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

then implement this contract somewhere (you can even implement it in `SelfHostService`, but, actually, you shouldn't), configure DI-container to use your implementation, and use it from controller:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IValueProvider _valueProvider;

    public ValuesController(IValueProvider valueProvider)
    {
        _valueProvider = valueProvider;
    }

    // the rest of code here
}
```

Note, that usually DI-containers allow to build parent/child hierarchy.
To reflect this, Web API DI approach uses *scopes* for this (see `IDependencyResolver.BeginScope` method).

There are global scope and child scopes. The Web API host creates global scope when it starts. This scope lives until host listens for requests. Host creates child scopes, when request is received, and host needs to create a controller to respond.

DI containers differ a little, when manage lifetime of objects, that were created using container. But the common is to place dependencies to the scope, where they needed. So, if you want to build some "global" dependency, then you need to place it into global scope.