# Communicate with windows service via api selfhosted with owin

Tags: c#, windows-services, owin, webapi

I have created a windows service that collects data from devices that use modbus and since now everything is working fine.
Now what I need is to communicate with this service and send/receive various commands.
I found Owin to selfhost api on the service and I was thinking to interact with the service instance from them but I'm not capable of doing it (api work but don't know how to get to the ServiceBase instance from them).
Is it even possible to access from the api my ServiceBase class and do some stuff there?
If not, how can I communicate with my service in a simple way similar to api?

What I'm trying to do is almost the same thing as this over here [Pass ServiceBase class instance to ApiController hosted on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32374489/pass-servicebase-class-instance-to-apicontroller-hosted-on-it)

Comment: Implement a Web API for the queries and commands you want to use?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I need to execute commands like StartCollect and StopCollect that my service already implements, that's why I'm trying to comminicate directly with the win service

Comment: I doubt you can do that without writing code. You will almost certainly have to create endpoints you can talk to to bridge the gap.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen What I'm trying to do is almost the same thing as this over here (the only difference is that my SelfHostedService class has multiple methods that I'm trying to access via the API) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32374489/pass-servicebase-class-instance-to-apicontroller-hosted-on-it

Comment: And as you can see, that person has implemented a small API for the methods that are required. I think you will have to do the same.